# Vscode - Is it possible to launch two urls on serverReadyAction?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode there is an option in **.vscode/launch.json** that you can launch a url when the server is ready.

Is it possible to launch two urls in the same launch configuration?

In my case I'm launching an api that contains swagger, and it depends on a prelaunch task that starts up a docker compose that contains redis insights.

Would be nice to launch both urls when the launch is completed.

Alternatively I know that I can do this using compounds configurations.

Comment: yes, I know that. What is in the launch config's `"type"` property? That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: node, request launch

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. And please also consider reading [ask].